# Find all products without pictures on Prestashop 1.6

Tags: sql, database, prestashop

I'm looking for a solution to find all my products which don't have pictures.

The website is running with Prestashop 1.6.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

To everyone who landing on this page, here the solution :

```
SELECT id_product
FROM ps_product
WHERE id_product
NOT IN (SELECT id_product 
FROM ps_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN()` can exhibit poor performance under certain circumstances and for these cases I generally prefer `NOT EXISTS()` as it is more explicit.

```
SELECT id_product
  FROM ps_product
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
             SELECT *
               FROM ps_image
              WHERE ps_image.id_product = ps_product.id_product
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also left join both tables and filter out all the `id_product` from `ps_image table` that match:

```
SELECT
  pp.id_product
FROM
  ps_product pp
LEFT JOIN
  ps_image pi ON pp.id_product = pi.id_product
WHERE
  pi.id_product IS NULL
```